# storing business hours in Parse DB

Tags: parse-platform

Need some help with the infrastructure with storing business hours for a location on Parse.com, i already tried it as a separate Class called BusinessHours, where each row has a pointer to the Location class. Having a minimum of 7 rows for each day of the week for 1 location, the objects count comes to +10.000

[image: data browser screenshot Class BusinessHours]

than in swift i do this to determine if the location is open now

```
        for hour in hours {
           if hour.isClosedAllDay {
             isOpen = "closed".localized
           }else{
            let now = NSDate()

            if  now.hasDayOffset(hour.weekday, closeWeekDay: hour.nextWeekday) {
                if hour.open != nil && hour.close != nil {
                    let open = now.hourDateFromString(hour.open!, offset: now.dayOpenOffset(hour.weekday, closeWeekDay: hour.nextWeekday))
                    let close = now.hourDateFromString(hour.close!, offset: now.dayCloseOffset(hour.weekday, closeWeekDay: hour.nextWeekday))
                    if now.isBetween(open, close: close) {

                        isOpen = "open".localized
                        timeOfBusiness = hour.time!
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this than to have thousands of rows for Business Hours only? I was thinking of adding a object field to the Location Class for the hours but don't know if that is the right way to go either.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to edit and change the details, and the complexities of multiple opening times per day, I'd consider not using multiple columns and rows. Instead, you could simply store a JSON string in a single column which contains all of the required details.

Obviously you wouldn't be able to use this for querying, so if you need to do that then you need to keep something more like your current solution.

If you don't need querying, or you need simple querying like 'is it open at all on a Monday' then a combined solution, supported by cloud code so the app doesn't need lots of knowledge of the JSON, could work well. For instance you could have columns for general open hours each day and then details in JSON, so you can get a rough answer by querying and then check the exact detail before presentation / usage of the result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! No I don't need to query it, i just loop through the hours of each location presented, to check if its open. A JSON string would be good to use but not in combination with cloud code, because i build my app to make use of the parse local-store when a connection is not present. So does it mean i would need a long JSON string with all the weekdays and its details? or is there a simpler way of doing this considering that i also store details of multiple opening times per day. How would such a string look like?

Comment: Cut it however is logical for your usage. Single column with all JSON, or column per day with specific JSON in each, any way will work - decide based on how you use the information for each day

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this in an array field called businessHours in my Location class:

```
[
    {"close":"20:00Z","open":"12:00Z","time":"09:00 - 17:00","isClosedAllDay":false,"nextWeekday":1,"weekday":1},
    {"close":"20:00Z","open":"12:00Z","time":"09:00 - 17:00","isClosedAllDay":false,"nextWeekday":2,"weekday":2},
    {"close":"20:00Z","open":"12:00Z","time":"09:00 - 17:00","isClosedAllDay":false,"nextWeekday":3,"weekday":3},
    {"close":"20:00Z","open":"12:00Z","time":"09:00 - 17:00","isClosedAllDay":false,"nextWeekday":4,"weekday":4},
    {"close":"20:00Z","open":"12:00Z","time":"09:00 - 17:00","isClosedAllDay":false,"nextWeekday":5,"weekday":5},
    {"close":"20:00Z","open":"12:00Z","time":"09:00 - 17:00","isClosedAllDay":false,"nextWeekday":6,"weekday":6},
    {"close":"20:00Z","open":"12:00Z","time":"09:00 - 17:00","isClosedAllDay":false,"nextWeekday":7,"weekday":7}
]
```

and then looping through the objects as a NSDictionary.

thanks Wain!